# C# WPF ComboBox with rounded corners IsMouseOver won't work

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I found this code on doing rounded corners on combobox, I have modifyed it a little, but I have two Issues:

1) The mouseover on the combobox (textbox + togglebutton) won't
work. (I want the standard bahavior with blue background on mouseover, put red just to see if something happend)

2) when I click on the togglebutton I get the popup, but how can I make the textbox clickable to get the popup?

This is what I get:

[image]

[image]

This is what I want when mouseover (but with rounded corner)

[image]

Here are the code:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderStyle">
    <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="#A0A1A2" />
    <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="#101010" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontFamily" Value="Arial" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontStretch" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="Control.FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
                            BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="#A0A1A2">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Border Background="#EAEAEA" 
                        x:Name="border" 
                        CornerRadius="0,2,2,0" 
                        BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                        BorderBrush="#A0A1A2">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style  x:Key="RoundComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14px"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <TextBox Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                             Padding="0,0,0,0"
                             IsHitTestVisible="False"
                             Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                             BorderBrush="#A0A1A2"
                             Background="#EAEAEA"
                             Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}"/>

                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" 
                                  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxButtonStyle}"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  ClickMode="Press">
                        <Path Grid.Column="1"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                              Fill="Black" />
                    </ToggleButton>

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                      Name="ContentSite"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      Margin="6,0,0,0"/>

                    <Popup Grid.Column="0" 
                           Name="Popup"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">

                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">

                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="2"
                                    Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="#A0A1A2"/>
                            <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>

                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Can you please post the image, how ComboBox appears with the mentioned template?

Comment: @user1672994 of course =)

Comment: `ComboBoxButtonStyle` needs `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`, and a Setter to set the default background of #EAEAEA. Still looking at the text box style; one problem is the actual textbox in the combobox template has an attribute for background, which will override the style entirely. But it's not just that.

Comment: The textbox has `IsHitTestVisible="False"`. That prevents it from getting any mouse messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few problems here. Each item I changed in the XAML is commented.

I've also removed the IsMouseOver triggers from the togglebutton and textbox styles, and put it in the ComboBox style. It now sets the background for the whole combobox when the mouse is anywhere over the ComboBox. The two controls in the ComboBox template now have `Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"`, so they'll use the background color set by that trigger.

I've restored `IsHitTestVisible` on the textbox, but used a TemplateBinding to bind it to the ComboBox's `IsEditable` property. This will give you the correct mouse pointer over the textbox.

```
<!-- 
Better to define this in one place. 
I'd do the same with the border color that you use everywhere. 
-->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBackgroundBrush" Color="#EAEAEA" />

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <!-- 
    Must set this in a setter, not an an attribute on the control instance.
    The attribute you had will override anything the style does. This is part of 
    "dependency property value precedence". 
    -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border CornerRadius="2,0,0,2"
                            BorderThickness="1,1,0,1"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="#A0A1A2"
                            >
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBackgroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <!-- 
                Needs {TemplateBinding Background} so it uses whatever background brush 
                the control has at any given moment.
                -->
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        x:Name="border" 
                        CornerRadius="0,2,2,0" 
                        BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"
                        BorderBrush="#A0A1A2">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ComboBoxOverlayToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid Background="Transparent" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="RoundComboBox" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14px"/>
    <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                        <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="18"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ToggleButton
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxOverlayToggleButtonStyle}"
                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        />

                    <!--
                    Two problems: 
                        1. IsHitTestVisible="False" prevented it from getting any mouse messages.
                        2. Background attribute was overriding anything the Style did,
                           so even if the trigger had fired, its setter would have failed. 
                    Also, Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" is unnecessary. It'll size to its parent Grid.
                    And BorderBrush="#A0A1A2" should probably be in the Style
                    -->
                    <TextBox Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                             Padding="0,0,0,0"
                             BorderBrush="#A0A1A2"
                             Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxStyle}"
                             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                             IsHitTestVisible="{TemplateBinding IsEditable}"
                             />

                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1" 
                                  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                  Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxButtonStyle}"
                                  Focusable="False"
                                  IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                  ClickMode="Press"
                                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                  >
                        <Path Grid.Column="1"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                              Fill="Black" />
                    </ToggleButton>

                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" 
                                      Name="ContentSite"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                      ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                      Margin="6,0,0,0"
                                      />

                    <Popup Grid.Column="0" 
                           Name="Popup"
                           Placement="Bottom"
                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                           Focusable="False"
                           PopupAnimation="Slide">

                        <Grid Name="DropDown"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"                
                              MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                              MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">

                            <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                    BorderThickness="1"
                                    CornerRadius="2"
                                    Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="#A0A1A2"/>
                            <ScrollViewer SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>

                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```